# Aggregating over Distinct Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The data model I have is: `(Item)-[:HAS_AN]->(ItemType)` and both node types have a field called `ID`. `Item`s can be related to multiple `ItemType`s and in some cases, these `ItemType`s can have the same `ID`s. I'm trying to populate a structure `{ID:..., SameType:...}`, where `SameType = 1` if a node has the same item type as some node (with `ID = 1234`), and 0 otherwise.

First, I get the candidate list of nodes `qList` and the source node's `ItemType`:

```
MATCH (p:Item{ID:1234})-[:HAS_AN]->(i)
WITH i as pItemType, qList
```

Then, I go through `qList`, comparing each node's `ItemType` to `pItemType` (which is the `ItemType` of the source node):

```
UNWIND qList as q
MATCH (q)-[:HAS_AN]->(i)
WITH q.ID as qID, pItemType, i,
CASE i
    WHEN pItemType THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END as SameType
RETURN DISTINCT i, qID, pItemType, SameType
```

The problem I have is when some nodes have two `ItemType`s with the same `ID`. This gives results where some of the entries are duplicates:

```
{           |                | {               |
  "ID": 18  |    35258417    |     "ID": 71    |    0
}           |                | }               |
            
{           |                | {               |
  "ID": 18  |    35258417    |     "ID": 71    |    0
}           |                | }               |
```

while I'd like to only take one such row, if more than one exists.
Placing `DISTINCT` where I have in the last part of the query doesn't seem to work. What's the best way to filter out such duplicates?

**Update:**

Here is a sample data subset: http://console.neo4j.org/r/f74pdq

Here are the queries that I'm running

```
MATCH (q:Item) WHERE q.ID <> 1234 WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT(q)) as qList
MATCH (p:Item{ID:1234})-[:HAS_AN]->(i:ItemType) WITH i as pItemType, qList 
UNWIND qList as q 
MATCH (q)-[:HAS_AN]->(i:ItemType) WITH q.ID as qID, pItemType, i,
CASE i
WHEN pItemType THEN 1
ELSE 0 
END as SameType 
RETURN DISTINCT i, qID, pItemType, SameType
```

In this example, `Item` with `ID = 2` has two `HAS_AN` relations with 2 `ItemType` nodes with the same `ID`. I would like only one of them to be returned.

Comment: Please, can you post the entire query you are running? Thanks.

Comment: So, I think I did not understood your question completely, but try changing your `RETURN` statement to `WITH collect({i : i, qID : qID, pItemType : pItemType, SameType : SameType})[0] as item
RETURN item.i, item.qID, item.pItemType, item.SameType`.

Comment: That returned only one row. I think it only returns the very first one from the `COLLECT()`?

Comment: Yes, you should specify a field to group before `collect(...)`, like `WITH i AS i, collect({i : i, qID : qID, pItemType : pItemType, SameType : SameType})[0] as item RETURN item.i, item.qID, item.pItemType, item.SameType`.

Comment: Which is the appropriate field to group over? If I use `WITH i AS i`, I get only one row even for nodes where there are two `ItemTypes` but with different IDs.

Comment: Can you share 1) a [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/) with some sample data set and 2) the complete query you are running?

Comment: 1) If I just run some CREATE queries on that link and send you the URL, would it work? 2) This is an MCVE. The entire query has lots of extraneous nodes and structures.

Comment: Yes, a link is enough. Also, send me a query (can be a MCVE query) that produces the wrong result.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to simplify your query. Take a look:

```
MATCH (:Item {ID : 1234})-[:HAS_AN]->(target:ItemType)

MATCH (item:Item)-[:HAS_AN]->(itemType:ItemType)
WHERE item.ID <> 1234

WITH
    itemType.ID AS i, 
    item.ID AS qID,
    collect({
        pItemType : target,
        SameType : CASE exists((item)-[:HAS_AN]-(target))
                    WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    })[0] as Item

RETURN i, qID, Item.pItemType AS pItemType, Item.SameType AS SameType
```

The trick is in the two lines after `WITH`. At this point I'm grouping by `itemType.ID` and `item.ID` and not ( and not `itemType` and `item`). In your original query you are using `pItemType` to group. This does not work because the two `ItemType`s with `ID = 34` are different nodes although they have the same ID.

The output from your console:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| i  | qID | pItemType     | SameType |
+-------------------------------------+
| 31 | 4   | Node[2]{ID:5} | 0        |
| 5  | 3   | Node[2]{ID:5} | 1        |
| 31 | 5   | Node[2]{ID:5} | 0        |
| 45 | 5   | Node[2]{ID:5} | 0        |
| 5  | 1   | Node[2]{ID:5} | 1        |
| 34 | 2   | Node[2]{ID:5} | 0        |
+-------------------------------------+
6 rows
33 ms
```

Comment: Thanks, this does give me the right results, but it increased the number of DB hits 4 times. Are there are any modifications you could suggest? I need the query to be in the form of `UNWIND qList ...` because I am using `qList` again later. Apart from that, I simplified your query to use `MATCH (item)-[:HAS_AN]->(itemType)` and `SameType : CASE IemType.ID WHEN pItemType.ID ...` and that brought it down to 2 times as many DB hits as the original query.

Comment: @Antimony  
I think you should not remove the labels from the MATCH. When using labels in the MATCH, Neo4j will use the auto created indexes to find the nodes. Also, can you share the complete altered query?

Comment: I've accepted your answer as the right one, since it did get me the right solution. I have shared my altered query as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Bruno's solution, I was able to get the right answers. However, the original solution did not work right off the bat for me for two reasons - I needed the `qList` since I was referring to it later, and it had approximately 4 times the DB hits as the query in my question. So, I tried a few optimizations that brought the number of DB hits down to half, and am sharing it here for posterity.

```
MATCH (q:Item) WHERE q.ID <> 1234 WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT(q)) as qList

MATCH (p:Item{ID:1234})-[:HAS_AN]->(i:ItemType) WITH i as pItemType, qList 

UNWIND qList as item 
MATCH (item)-[:HAS_AN]->(i)
WITH
    i, pItemType,
    item.ID AS qID,
    collect({
        pItemType : pItemType,
        SameType : CASE i.ID
                WHEN pItemType.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    })[0] as Item

RETURN i, qID, Item.pItemType AS pItemType, Item.SameType AS SameType
```

Turns out running `MATCH (item:Item)-[:HAS_AN]->(itemType:ItemType)` was adding a `Filter` operation that took almost as many DB hits as it had matches.